# Pandas Datarame to dict

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[111,222,333]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

     A    B    C
0    1    2    3
1  111  222  333
2   11   22   33
```

I need to convert each row in A and C to dict.
I should be able to get this:

```
{'1':'3',
 '111':'333',
 '11':'33'}
```

So far, I have not been able to find how to chose which columns should be included and how to not include the headers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `zip`

```
dict(zip(df.A,df.C))
Out[1073]: {1: 3, 11: 33, 111: 333}
```

Update

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(dict)
for _,x in df.iterrows():
    d[x['A']][x['B']] = x['C']


d
Out[74]: defaultdict(dict, {1: {2: 3}, 11: {22: 33}, 111: {222: 333}})
```

Comment: @AnonX aha , yw~ :-) happy coding

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again. At the moment I have {A:C}, but is there a way to generate {A:{B:C}}?

Comment: @AnonX that is no brothering , :-), updated , you need nested dict :-)

Comment: Thank you! :) And how to remove the "defaultdict(dict," and ")" so I'm left with the raw dict?
EDIT: oh.. haha.. "dict(d)" it was that simple ^^ Thank you!

Comment: @AnonX yw~ :-) happy coding

Answer (score 2):

This is one way:

```
d = df.set_index('A')['C'].to_dict()
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys! Here's just in case someone wonders the difference in optimization:

```
%%timeit
d1 = df.set_index('A')['C'].to_dict()

[Out]: 2.46 ms ± 11.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

```
%%timeit
d2 = dict(zip(df['A'],df['C']))

[Out]: 1.23 ms ± 12.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```